# Designing a voltage-current converter circuit to drive a coil as a mutual inductance antenna

Tags: circuit-design, antenna, coil, power-amplifier, mutual-inductance

I'm trying to design a voltage to current converter circuit to drive a coil antenna to transmit an analog signal through mutual inductance (very short range, around 3 inches). My frequency range is between 20 kHz - 2 MHz.

Ideally I would be able to drive this circuit with an ADC and obtain the same proportional voltage across the coil antenna. I am currently aiming for a 0.5 V amplitude sine wave to be attainable across the antenna at all operating frequencies (my thought is that if this is attainable in simulation, I should be able to send any analog signal composed of this frequency range at this strength).

These are my current antenna loop parameters. I'm not against changing any of these parameters to attain a more desirable inductance, but the antenna needs to be attached to a handheld device (so it can't be too large). I'm not able to access the receiving antenna to take measurements, but I know it cannot be physically larger than what my current antenna is.

TURNS: 16
GAUGE: 20
DIAMETER: 6.3 cm
LENGTH: 1.5 cm
INDUCTANCE: 23.1 uH (calculated using https://www.66pacific.com/calculators/coil-inductance-calculator.aspx)

I am currently simulating using this circuit described by TI.
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa325/sboa325.pdf?ts=1697371515490&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FCIRCUIT060014.

[image: TI voltage-current circuit]

My thought is that some combination of resistive network, op-amp, and npn bjt will allow me to drive the load (replaced with my antenna) how I want. I am finding this difficult to realize in simulation however, with significant stability and signal strength issues. Below is my LTSpice circuit and simulation for a 200 kHz sine wave. In the simulation we can see stability issues and a tiny signal.

[image: LT Spice Circuit]
[image: LT Spice Simulation]

Op Amp Datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6228-6229.pdf
BJT Datasheet: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mj14001-d.pdf

If someone could help me pick out a better op amp/bjt/resistive network, their help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Coil is not a resistor. You can’t expect you can limit its current with transistor limiter you post. It  is because inductor takes current according the voltage it is supplied with lag. So you have to control the coil current with supply voltage. I would use a totem-pole transistor topology(PNP+NPN emitter followers) and take a current feedback from coil shunt.